# Embed Code in Popup or modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have come across one issue for getting an embedded link in modal box so that embed code can be shared to any one to use in their websites.

I have tried to some extent to get the popup when I click a button and open the embed link content in the popup.

But the lines to be shared to the user will be more. So, looking for simple way to acheive it.

```
`<div class="container">
<h2>Click on the link below</h2>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Reserve Table</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<embed width="800" height="685" src="http://find-out-pro.co/pcktnight/projet1/reservations_website.html?member_id=56&langs=all&place=101" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `<iframe>` instead of `embed`

I've made a JSFiddle to show you:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <iframe id="videoContainer" width="800" height="685" src="http://find-out-pro.co/pcktnight/projet1/reservations_website.html?member_id=56&langs=all&place=101" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8crmo0j/)